# Issue with detecting viewport resizing

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I'm working on a project that requires that the vertical borders, which are currently calculated based on page size or the length of the page depending on which one is longer, but there is a slight issue.

I am using Firefox and for example if my `noscript` plugin *kicks in* and I for example allowed the script the vertical borders will have a gap at the bottom of the page.

That as an example, is there any way I am able to use javascript to detect a viewport change across multiple browsers?

I found somewhere `watch()` but was unable to find solid documentation on it and what browsers support this. Is what I am trying to do possible? Is `watch()` the proper way? If so, can anyone point me to some documentation, if not, what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.onresize` is the event you're looking for, I think. Here's a link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize

However, you should be able to get full-height elements using only CSS, and then you won't need any javascript

Comment: I recommend combining that with an event debouncing function, since the resize event fires every 20ms when resizing, an no one could possibly need to execute anything on every resize event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this problem with **Media Queries** and `window.matchMedia`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/06/using-window-matchmedia-to-do-media-queries-in-javascript/